# How to rewrite SQL query to JPQL properly

Tags: sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have created a `SQL` query which I want to rewrite to `JPQL`. Below there is a `SQL` query and my example of `JPQL`. I need to inform you that in `SQL` query I use the function table called `wash_admin` which is not mapped into `Java` class.
`SQL` query:

```
 select ww.wash_id, ww.name, ww.washlocation_wash from test3.user us 
    join test3.admin ad on us.user_id = ad.user_id
    join test3.wash_admin wa on wa.admin_id = ad.admin_id
    join test3.wash ww on ww.wash_id = wa.wash_id
    where 1=1
    and us.login = 'ADMIN11';
```

My `JPQL`:

```
@Query(value = "select w from Wash w left join w.washAdmins wa left join wa.userId us where us.login = :login")
    List<Wash> getWashByLogin(@Param("login") String login);
```

`Wash`:

```
public class Wash {
    private Integer washId;
    private String name;
    private WashLocation washLocation;
    private List<Worker> washWorker;
    private List<Reservation> washReservation;
    private List<WashWashType> washTypes;
    private List<Admin> washAdmins;
```

`User`:

```
public class User {

    private Integer userId;
    private String login;
    private String passwordHash;
    private Role userRole; // admin, worker, client
    private Client userClient;
    private Worker userWorker;
    private List<File> file;
    private Admin userAdmin;
```

`Admin`:

```
public class Admin {
    private Integer adminId;
    private User userId;
    private List<Wash> washId;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "wash_admin", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "adminId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "washId") })
    public List<Wash> getWashId() {
        return washId;
    }
```

Unfortunately when I ran this `query` I got exception:

```
Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

But the main questoion in that topic is to how to rewrite it properly to get result the same as it is in `SQL` query?

Answer (score 0):

I foung myself the solution. The case why I got the fails was wrong import. It's important to take `import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;`